# C# Connecting to Azure Media Services Account using REST API

Tags: c#, rest, azure, access-token, azure-media-services

I'm trying to get access token following this documentation https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-rest-connect-programmatically/

My code now looks like this:

```
 string requestUrl = String.Format("https://MyAccessControlNamespace.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13");
 string bodyURL = string.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MyMediaServicesAccountName&client_secret=MyAccountKeyEncodedToUrl&scope=urn%3aWindowsAzureMediaServices");

 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
 request.Method = "POST";
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 request.Accept = "application/json";

 byte[] requestBodyBytes = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(bodyURL);
 Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
 requestStream.Write(requestBodyBytes, 0, requestBodyBytes.Length);

 var response = (HttpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

I have also tried using HttpClient. But I'm always getting 400 Bad Request error...

I'll be very grateful for any help/hints!

Comment: Can you grab a fiddler request? It looks like it is malformed for some reason

Comment: may help - Azure Media Services Error Codes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn168949.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much for the hints! Fiddler showed "error: invalid_client", so I guess I haven't done the right setup in Active Directory or something. 
Anyway, I decided to create Web API App with Media Services .NET SDK, because I got stuck with this.

Answer (score 0):

Media Services access control address is https://wamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net/. It is not the Access Control Namespaces of AD.

Change to :
`string requestUrl = String.Format("https://wamsprodglobal001acs.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13");`

Make sure your media account key is encoded.